# Getting 404 error using cURL in PHP trying to copy SHA2 cert

Tags: php, curl, sha2

I have an app that was working fine until the vendor changed certificates - to SHA2 certificate.

My PHP app uses cURL to copy the certificate to my server. Now I get a 404 error.

Is this expected behavior with this type of file? What do I need to do to properly copy the cert?

Comment: this is not a php problem. you're specifying a url which doesn't exist, and are getting the expected 404 - file not found.

Comment: @Marc B - You're correct. The URL was provided by the vendor also. At first I didn't notice and was chasing ghosts. But they corrupted the URL by adding '\n' to it. Finally picked it up in logs.